# Hazelcast partition lost behavior with initial-mode="LAZY/EAGER"

Tags: java, caching, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am wondering that how **initial-mode="LAZY/EAGER"** behave at a partition lost.

According to the online documentations
EAGER - Synchronously loads the entries. Calls to getMap() are blocked while this happens

I need to know how the lost partition are loading in following scenarios...

1 ) Node crash and lost partition  when there is a backup in another node

- will that lost partition data loaded from DB or backup ?
- if this is loaded from DB ,How the initial-mode="LAZY/EAGER" affect for map
  loading ?
- Will that lost partition migrated to the node where the
  backup is available or can it be possible to migrate to completely
  new node ?

2 )  Node crash and lost partition when there is no any backup in another node

- In this scenario lost partition data will be loaded from DB
- How the initial-mode="LAZY/EAGER" affect for map loading when there is no any backup ?

When initial-mode="LAZY" ,
Instantly after partition lost, i can see it relocated in another node , I think that is only the partition creation not with data

[image]

In this image you can see the partition ID 87 lost and instantly partition summery shows it is relocated in another node

**62- ( LOM:FE44 )** =  partionID - ( partition key )

Answer (score 2):

First lets begin by understanding the fundamental differences between the backup options:
Synchronous - default 1 [backup-count]
Asynchronous - default 0 [async-backup-count]

By default we have strong consistency because:
Client map.put(foo) -> Primary two threads: T1 operational thread stores in partition on Primary while T2 stores on Backup. T1 and T2 Join prior to returning to Client. So once the return from map.put occurs the data is safely stored in two locations.

In the event you set [backup-count] to 0 and [async-backup-count] >0 then you will have eventual consistency since T1 and T2 will *not* be joined prior to returning to the client; instead once T1 finishes the server returns to the Client.

So now lets look at your questions:
1 ) Node crash and lost partition when there is a backup in another node
will that lost partition data loaded from DB or backup ?
We have not discussed a MapStore (which is one of several ways to store the data into a database) but if you have implemented a Map Store then it would be restored from there in the event of a cache miss.

if this is loaded from DB ,How the initial-mode="LAZY/EAGER" affect for map loading ?
Lazy will only load the partition data (think 1/271th of the data by default) versus Eager which will load the full map (271/271th of the data)

Will that lost partition migrated to the node where the backup is available or can it be possible to migrate to completely new node ?
The backup will immediately restore the partition from the lost server. The backup which is now primary will solicit a new backup.

2 ) Node crash and lost partition when there is no any backup in another node
If you fail to set [backup-count] and [async-backup-count] and MapStore and you are not using HotRestart then you just lost data. But you had to change our defaults in order to create this situation.

In this scenario lost partition data will be loaded from DB
How the initial-mode="LAZY/EAGER" affect for map loading when there is no any backup ?
Again it determines how much of the map data will be loaded and if you have a map store it means how many load(key) will be invoked on your DB.

Hope this helps,